# How does MySQL handle the SUM function?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT 
   COUNT(id) as t,
   IF(pageId is NULL, 1, 0) as tD
FROM table_name;
```

| t | td |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 |

```
SELECT 
   COUNT(id) as t,
   SUM(IF(pageId is NULL, 1, 0)) as tD
FROM table_name;
```

| t | td |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | null |

Why does the second query return null if the first query returns 1?

Comment: You should also include the actual table data for the `table_name` table so that others may try to reproduce your current observations.

Comment: SQL questions that do not provide sample data often "do not work": See https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=70c20392cbb51ae928d186b08a80ba9c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first query is not legal SQL. You're using an aggregate function (count) but have a non aggregated column (pageId). MySQL will allow this if only_full_group_by is off. You should turn it on to avoid bad habits. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html and https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html

In the first query you asked for a count of all rows, so it has to return a row. You also asked for the value of pageId. There are no rows, so pageId is null, so `pageId is null` is true.

In the second query you asked to sum all the rows, but there are no rows to sum so you get null. What you're summing doesn't matter. `sum(1)` is also null.

> If there are no matching rows, or if expr is NULL, SUM() returns NULL.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_sum